# Why the value is not getting assigned in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code where i am trying to create a string from the selected value.

```
this.selectedCategory = selectedvalue.name;
this.filter = '{category:${this.selectedCategory}}';
```

The value of `this.filter` is **`{category:${this.selectedCategory}}`** while i am expecting the output as **`{category:Music}`**.

Comment: its treated as string interpolation. use template specific quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes ', but you should use ` instead for the string interpolation:

```
this.selectedCategory = selectedvalue.name;
this.filter = `{category:${this.selectedCategory}}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ` instead of ' for template literals. Otherwise it's just a simple string.

```
this.filter = `{category:${this.selectedCategory}}`;
```

You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).